# Are Memcached and Redis types of NoSQL databases?

Tags: redis, nosql, memcached

I know MongoDB and CouchDB belong to the NoSQL family. However, I'd like to know whether Memcached and Redis are also NoSQL databases?

I see that they're caching systems, is that what NoSQL is? Or it's something completely different?

Answer (score 3):

[List Of NoSQL Databases [currently 122+]](http://nosql-database.org/)